# Subsequential limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Hey I need to find the limit superior and limit inferior of this sequence,

I didn't manage to get rid of the n^2 to get a real number,

I will glad if you could help me solve the question.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Substitute the taylor series for cosine and the first two factors simplify to something nice.

Answer (score 0):

As $n \to \infty,$ the cosine term tends to $\cos(-1).$
Therefore

$$\left|a_n - n^2 \cos(-1) \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right| \to 0.$$

From here, you can show that the sequence $a_n$ takes both arbitrarily large positive values and arbitrarily large negative values so limsup is $\infty$ while liminf is $-\infty.$